# ardrone_automony is not receiving correct navdata from AR.Drone2.0

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been running ardrone_autonomy with an AR.Drone1.0 and it has been working great. Today I bought an AR.Drone2.0 and assumed that my code would work out of the box. Unfortunately ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver throws this error over and over again:

```
One option (0) is not a valid option because its size is zero
[Navdata] Checksum failed : 1006 (distant) / 34055 (local)
Tag 12504 is an unknown navdata option tag
```

Is there something I need to change in the code / launch file to make it compatible with the AR.Drone2.0?

I should also mention (though I don't think it's relevant) that I modified ardrone_autonomy to make it catkin compatible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91226/ardrone_automony-is-not-receiving-correct-navdata-from-ar.drone2.0/) by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to look for the drone firmware.
it must be 2.3.3

look here
https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/issues/69

we are all waiting for the new sdk from parrot

---

Originally posted by [mmyself](https://answers.ros.org/users/1194/mmyself/) with karma: 138 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on 2013-10-29**:
Worked like charm, firmware was very easy to downgrade. Thanks!